# Can we use JavaScript for creating iPhone apps?

Tags: javascript, ios

I just want to know if we can use JavaScript for creating iPhone apps. And if we can how do we do it? Do I have to become an expert in JavaScript to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.. No need to be an expert to do that.. Search & explore about Phonegap.. You can develop html css javascript based application & wrap them for any mobile os like iOS, android or windows phone 8 etc.

Best of all, its too easy to learn & use
Here's the place to start from

[phonegap home](http://www.phonegap.com)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. 
You can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

- Yes
- You can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) which is a wrapper of embedded browser
- You should be an expert if you're seriously working on the project.